# Find the limit of $\left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^{2}} \exp(-2n)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: limits

> Find the limit of $\left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^{2}} \exp(-2n)$ as $n \to \infty$.

By expansion -
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left[1+(n^{2})(2/n) + (n^{2})(n^{2}-1)/2 \dots ]/[1+2n+(2n)^{3}/3! \dots\right]$$

I didn't get any result. 
By applying limit directly, I'm getting indeterminate form. 
How to find this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^{2}} \exp(-2n)=\exp\left(n^2\log\left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right)-2n\right).$$
Now, by using the expansion $\log(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)$ at $t=0$, we have that
$$\log\left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right)=\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n^2}+o(1/n^2).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Okay, I got exp(-2). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: maybe $O(1/n^3)$?

Comment: @JohnJoy Yes, here we can replace $o(1/n^2)$ with $O(1/n^3)$, but $o(1/n^2)$ suffices.